# Figure references in tufte-book

Tags: cross-referencing, tufte

With the `tufte-book` class I cannot get references for figures right.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 
\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Demo option for MWE without image
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\newpage
\Blindtext

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics{img1}
\label{fig:l1}
\caption{some image}
\end{marginfigure}
\Blindtext

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics{img2}
\label{fig:l2}
\caption{any other image}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

The entries in the list of figures only refer to the page itself (here the first page).

Comment: Always place the `label` *after* or *within* the `caption`.

Comment: Forgive me, I was too quick in voting to close, the issue isn't related to the label position. (Reviewers: don't vote to close.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem: The LoF shows correctly, that "some figure" is on page 3 and "any other image" is on page 4.

Comment: @DG' The hyperlink doesn't work though.

Comment: You are right, this is a problem with the `hyperref`package, which could be solved by calling the document class with the option `nohyper` and using `\usepackage{bookmark}` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the problem is, that the hyperlinks within the pdf do not work properly, although the correct page numbers are displayed in the LoF. A possible solution would be to call `tufte-book`with the option `nohyper` and to use the package `bookmark`instead of `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Demo option for MWE without image
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\newpage
\Blindtext

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics{img1}
\label{fig:l1}
\caption{some image}
\end{marginfigure}
\Blindtext

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics{img2}
\label{fig:l2}
\caption{any other image}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```