# How to hyperlink to figure instead of head of section

Tags: hyperref, tufte

I have a problem with the PDF output of a tufte-handout ([here](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/browse/sample-handout.tex) the MWE, you also need the these two files to compile: [tufte-handout.cls](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/browse/tufte-handout.cls) and [tufte-common.def](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/browse/tufte-common.def)). I am not sure the problem is with the template, but in my PDF when I click on some reference in the text (where I placed the \ref) instead of linking to the referenced figure or table, the hyperlink goes to the head of section.

Comment: Is that the same problem described in [Figure references in tufte-book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134633/35864)?

Comment: Indeed. I had missed that. My bad.