# Figure referencing in tufte-book pointing to section instead

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, tufte

The `\ref` command usually points to the figure/table/etc that is referenced by `\label`. However in the tufte-book document class this does not seem to work:

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\section{Newsection}
Some text here.
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig:f1}
\end{figure*}
Please see Fig.~\ref{fig:f1} for more information.
\end{document}
```

Instead, the reference simply points quietly to the section header above without giving an error. I tried putting the `\label` command in different places or using different figure environments (`figure*`, `figure`, `marginfigure`). I am using the `pdflatex` command to compile the above example, I have the `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)` distribution.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: i can't reproduce your problem. referencing works correctly. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: well, then there is hope that I will figure out my problem. Which operating system are you using? Which tex distribution?

Comment: I just found a similar question: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134633/figure-references-in-tufte-book?rq=1) but the solution seems to be a fudge (just using a different reference package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue turned out to be tufte-unrelated, so sorry for asking it here.

I opened the pdf of a windows machine using the adobe reader and all the links worked fine. Only on my mac (Preview) the links are broken.

I could start a new thread somewhere but for now I am more-or-less happy.

Answer (score 0):

this is extended comment ...

with your mwe i can reproduce problem which you reported in question. for better see, that referencing in your document working well, i slightly extend your code to:

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor={blue},
            breaklinks=true}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[11]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[12]
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption of the figure 1}
\label{fig:f1}
\setfloatalignment{b}
    \end{figure}

\section{Third section}
The basic idea is illustrated on the Fig.~\ref{fig:f2}.
\lipsum[13-14]
    \begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption of the figure 2}
\label{fig:f2}
    \end{figure*}
Please see Fig.~\ref{fig:f1} and Fig.~\ref{fig:f2} for more information.

\end{document}
```

all extension doesn't influence anyhow to working of hyper links. all works as it is expected. i test this code with recent MikTeX using pdfLaTeX engine. however i'm pretty sure that this should works with other not so recent `latex` installation too. please test my mwe and let me know, if it is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Zarko! Thanks for trying this out. I can compile your mwe but it shows the same symptoms as mine: the Fig. 1 reference points to 'Second section' header and Fig. 2 points to 'Third section' header. Maybe my TeX distribution is the problem since you're using MikTeX and I am using TeX Live.